# How to set 404 status code for 404 page in Next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server, next.js

How can I set the 404 status code for the custom 404-page in Next.js? I am a frontend, getting familiar with backend, but according to this thread https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10960
it should be possible to do in getStaticProps, but the thing is, perhaps I understand it incorrectly, but it allows doing stuff like returning notFound or redirect from getStaticProps only if the data that is fetched inside this function is e.g. empty so in this example

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params: { id } }) {
  const res = await fetchContentfulPosts();
  const posts = await res
    .filter((r) => r.sys.id === id)
    .map((p) => {
      return {
        fields: p.fields,
        locale: p.sys.locale,
        tags: p.metadata.tags,
      };
    });

  const { locale, fields, tags } = posts[0];
  const { title, author, date, image, text, shareDesc } = fields;

  if (!posts) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/404',
        statusCode: 301,
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      title,
      author,
      date,
      text,
      image: image || null,
      locale,
      tags,
      shareDesc
    },
  };
}
```

It would return 404 status only if the data returned from Contentful were empty, but what about if someone enters url that does not exist? Then I will get the 404 with the status code 200.
I also tried to modify the error page according to this doc https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page like so:

```
import { Layout, NotFoundComponent } from '../components';

function Error({ statusCode }) {
  return statusCode === 404 ? (
    <Layout title="404: This page could not be found" backgroundVideo noIndex>
      <NotFoundComponent />
    </Layout>
  ) : (
    <p>
      {statusCode
        ? `An error ${statusCode} occurred on server`
        : 'An error occurred on client'}
    </p>
  );
}

Error.getInitialProps = ({ res, err }) => {
  const statusCode = res ? res.statusCode : err ? err.statusCode : 404;
  return { statusCode };
};

export default Error;
```

But it seems that it only gets status code from the server and allows to display it, but not to set it to the server. I want all 404 hits to be returned with response code 404 so this would not be indexed.

Thanks very much!

Comment: _...what about if someone enters url that does not exist? Then I will get the 404 with the status code 200..._ - this is not true in Next.js, by default any request to a non-existing path will be responded with the 404 status code.

Comment: does this help https://nextjs.org/blog/next-10#notfound-support

Comment: I have tried solution from evgeni but I get Error: The /404 page can not return notFound in "getStaticProps", please remove it to continue! 
Basically the page that does not exist comes with the 404 status code, thats correct, but the 404 page is generated with status code 200, is it the correct behavior https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/soft-404-errors?hl=en&visit_id=637630574702568625-517773016&rd=1

Comment: @brc-dd actually this is true, non existing page has status 404 but i want my 404 to have status 404

Comment: @Seven I don't get it. What do you mean by "your 404"? Your custom 404 page that you created at `pages/404.jsx`? I believe that will also respond with status code 404 by default.

Comment: @brc-dd unfortunately not, this is exactly what i am tring to achieve, the ultimate goal is that if someone exters /dupa will be redirected to /404?url=%2Fdupa, I am a frontend this is all new for me and scary :) thanks a lot taht you bother to have a thought about it

Comment: @Seven I'm not sure I fully understand the issue you're having, however you can force a response code by setting `res.statusCode` in `getStaticProps`/`getServerSideProps`, e.g., `res.statusCode = 404`.

Comment: @juliomalves this seems like what i need thanks!